# Content Type Questions in Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type

I opened up a case with Microsoft as I think this is a bug, but wanted to ask the question here. My summary:

I have a library with 10 content types. A default content type of "Document" that has a template of document.dotx, two word document types, one PowerPoint type and eight excel templates.

The templates always load correctly. That is not the problem. The content types for the Word Document always display correctly, but all of the other ones default to the "Document" content type. This is even true if I make it not default.

Any insight? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by: "all of the other ones default to the "Document" content type". Do you mean that when you create a new file of based on one of the content types using an excel template, you get the word doc instead as the new file?

Comment: Yeah, microsoft delivered a fix (just republishing content types) but couldn't explain the problem. I escalated so hoping to hear back.